# What is a clean way to convert a string percent to a float?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have looked in the standard library and on StackOverflow, and have not found a similar question. So, is there a way to do the following without rolling my own function? Bonus points if someone writes a beautiful function if there is no built in way.

```
def stringPercentToFloat(stringPercent)
    # ???
    return floatPercent

p1 = "99%"
p2 = "99.5%"
print stringPercentToFloat(p1)
print stringPercentToFloat(p2)

>>>> 0.99
>>>> 0.995
```

Comment: Whence arises the issue?

Comment: I have a log with percent CPU usage, and percent memory usage, so it would be helpful to have this function so I can do sorting on the log entries.

Comment: "...without rolling my own function? Bonus points if someone writes a beautiful function." Are those conflicting requirements?

Comment: Yeah, that is a conflicting requirement. I have changed it to make it a little more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use `strip('%')` , as:

```
In [9]: "99.5%".strip('%')
Out[9]: '99.5'             #convert this to float using float() and divide by 100

In [10]: def p2f(x):
   ....:    return float(x.strip('%'))/100
   ....: 

In [12]: p2f("99%")
Out[12]: 0.98999999999999999

In [13]: p2f("99.5%")
Out[13]: 0.995
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not take locales into account. Most of the time the decimal point is a period (.), but in other countries it may be a comma (,), so the conversion will fail.

Comment: @krema Well, it's out of scope for this question. It makes no sense to mention `locale.atof` every time float is being used for conversion.

Answer (score 20):

```
float(stringPercent.strip('%')) / 100.0
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply replace the  `%`  by  `e-2`  before parsing to `float` :

```
float("99.5%".replace('%', 'e-2'))
```

It's safer since the result will still be correct if there's no `%` used.

Comment: very elegant solution, nice

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the following method that should always return the output to the exact same accuracy as the input, with no floating point errors such as in the other answers.

```
def percent_to_float(s):
    s = str(float(s.rstrip("%")))
    i = s.find(".")
    if i == -1:
        return int(s) / 100
    if s.startswith("-"):
        return -percent_to_float(s.lstrip("-"))
    s = s.replace(".", "")
    i -= 2
    if i < 0:
        return float("." + "0" * abs(i) + s)
    else:
        return float(s[:i] + "." + s[i:])
```

### Explanation

1. Strip the "%" from the end.
2. If percent has no ".", simply return it divided by 100.
3. If percent is negative, strip the "-" and re-call function, then convert the result back to a negative and return it.
4. Remove the decimal place.
5. Decrement `i` (the index the decimal place was at) by 2, because we want to shift the decimal place 2 spaces to the left.
6. If `i` is negative, then we need to pad with zeros.

   - **Example:** Suppose the input is "1.33%". To be able to shift the decimal place 2 spaces to the left, we would need to pad with a zero.
7. Convert to a float.

---

Test case ([Try it online](https://repl.it/@HatScripts/percenttofloat)):

```
from unittest.case import TestCase

class ParsePercentCase(TestCase):
    tests = {
        "150%"              : 1.5,
        "100%"              : 1,
        "99%"               : 0.99,
        "99.999%"           : 0.99999,
        "99.5%"             : 0.995,
        "95%"               : 0.95,
        "90%"               : 0.9,
        "50%"               : 0.5,
        "66.666%"           : 0.66666,
        "42%"               : 0.42,
        "20.5%"             : 0.205,
        "20%"               : 0.2,
        "10%"               : 0.1,
        "3.141592653589793%": 0.03141592653589793,
        "1%"                : 0.01,
        "0.1%"              : 0.001,
        "0.01%"             : 0.0001,
        "0%"                : 0,
    }
    tests = sorted(tests.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])

    def test_parse_percent(self):
        for percent_str, expected in self.tests:
            parsed = percent_to_float(percent_str)
            self.assertEqual(expected, parsed, percent_str)

    def test_parse_percent_negative(self):
        negative_tests = [("-" + s, -f) for s, f in self.tests]
        for percent_str, expected in negative_tests:
            parsed = percent_to_float(percent_str)
            self.assertEqual(expected, parsed, percent_str)
```

Comment: You went to a lot of work for nothing, there are no floating point errors in the other answers that yours doesn't have too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Well for instance in [Ashwini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432693/2203482) you can see that his one-liner method called like `p2f("99%")` returns `0.98999999999999999`, whereas if you try running the test case in my answer you would see that the same input string of "99%" will give you the expected output of `0.99`. Could you give an example of an input string to my method that would cause a floating point error?

Comment: Read the link I gave you. It's a matter of how it's printed, not the actual value. With Ashwini's answer I get `0.99` output on both Python 2.7.1 and 3.6.3. Yours returns `0` on 2.7.1 because of integer division.

Comment: For example, `'%0.20f' % parse_percent('99%')` returns `'0.98999999999999999112'`

Comment: Well I wrote my method for Python 3, and I wrote it because none of the other answers to this question, while succinct, satisfied my requirement of [consistently returning a float value without floating point errors](https://ideone.com/AmV1RJ).

Comment: Well that's because `'%0.20f' % 0.99` returns `'0.98999999999999999112'`. That has nothing to do with the parse_percent method.

Comment: the suggested method on negative numbers return error in the following case: ```print(percent_to_float('-10%'))``` and result  is:  ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'```.

Comment: @Cindy I think you may have copied it incorrectly. It should be start**s**with, not startwith.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from @WKPlus this solution takes into account the locales where the decimal point is either a point `.` or a comma `,`

```
float("-3,5%".replace(',','.')[:-1]) / 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
`float(stringPercent[:-1]) / 100`