# Convert percent string to float in pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file-io, percentage

**Is there a way to convert values like '34%' directly to int or float when using `read_csv()` command in pandas?** I want '34%' to be directly read as 0.34

1. Using this in `read_csv` did not work:

   `read_csv(..., dtype={'col':np.float})`
2. After loading the csv as 'df' this also did not work with the error "invalid literal for float(): 34%"

   `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)`
3. I ended up using this which works but is long winded:

   `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x in ['-'] else x[:-1]).astype(float)/100`

Comment: 1) and 2) fail because '34%' has to be a string, trying to coerce to `float('34%')` throws ValueError. First you must do .rstrip('%') on the offending percent sign.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can **define a custom function to convert your percents to floats at `read_csv()` time**:

```
# dummy data
temp1 = """index col 
113 34%
122 50%
123 32%
301 12%"""

# Custom function taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432663/what-is-a-clean-way-to-convert-a-string-percent-to-a-float
def p2f(x):
    return float(x.strip('%'))/100

# Pass to `converters` param as a dict...
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), sep='\s+',index_col=[0], converters={'col':p2f})
df

        col
index      
113    0.34
122    0.50
123    0.32
301    0.12

# Check that dtypes really are floats
df.dtypes

col    float64
dtype: object
```

My percent to float code is courtesy of ashwini's answer: [What is a clean way to convert a string percent to a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432663/what-is-a-clean-way-to-convert-a-string-percent-to-a-float)

Comment: This is the best approach, doing it at `read_csv()` time. But a note on `p2f()`, if you do the conversion later, doing `df['col'].apply(p2f, axis=1)` is less efficient than vectorized using the `.str.rstrip` accessor.

Answer (score 97):

You were very close with your `df` attempt.  Try changing:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
```

to:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
#                     ^ use str funcs to elim '%'     ^ divide by 100
# could also be:     .str[:-1].astype(...
```

Pandas supports Python's string processing functions on string columns. Just precede the string function you want with `.str` and see if it does what you need.  (This includes string slicing, too, of course.)

Above we utilize `.str.rstrip()` to get rid of the trailing percent sign, then we divide the array in its entirety by 100.0 to convert from percentage to actual value. For example, 45% is equivalent to 0.45.

Although `.str.rstrip('%')` could also just be `.str[:-1]`, I prefer to explicitly remove the '%' rather than blindly removing the last char, just in case...

Comment: I don't believe you need "100.0"; just "100" should do fine. It's already float64 by then.

Comment: This seems like the better answer? @EdChum do you agree?

Comment: if the column has a mixture of strings with % and floats converted to pandas object, the above will need to be changed to:

 pct = df['col'].str.contains('%')
 df.loc[pct, 'col'] = df.loc[pct, 'col'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0 
 df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)
to prevent floats divided by 100

Comment: nice and simple. THnx. I prefer this to the accepted answer that uses a function.