# Python - convert object data type to integer, string or float based on data in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following issue. I have a dataframe which has various types of columns (int, float, string, etc) - but since they were imported into python using a .csv file all columns are showing as `object`data type. Example is below:

```
print df_centers
```

output:

```
center name                      ID    state  activity type cost  usage
Bay area recreational facility  10019   LA       swimming    $15   0.5%
Ith area recreational facility  10020   NY       basketball  $200  100%
```

all of these columns have data type = object, i am trying to convert the object data types to their relevant and more meaningful data types. Example below:

```
df_centers['cost'] = df_centers['cost'].astype('int')
```

The reason i am trying to do an INT conversion on the cost field is because i have to do some analysis later on it but python returns with the following error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '$15'
```

i have also tried converting usage to 0.5% to float with the below and it returns the error message:

```
df_centers['usage'] = df_centers['usage'].astype('float')
```

output i get is:

```
invalid literal for float(): 100%
```

Any suggestions on how i can get this data type conversion done from object to a more relevant type?

Comment: See [Convert percent string to float in pandas read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669588/convert-percent-string-to-float-in-pandas-read-csv). You can use a similar method for the currency.

Comment: $XX and XX% is str 
   `df.cost=df.cost.str[1:]`
    `df.usage=df.usage.str[:-1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Wen and Galen. - i used Wen's suggestion to strip the leading $ value or the trailing % values and then i converted them to the types most relevant. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Usually in CSV files, if it's not just comma-delimited but rather an Excel file, etc, the "object" has a type and value which may help you decipher what's what.

In the interim, to convert money values to numbers, strip off the leading '$' and convert to float. For the percentages, strip off the %, convert the number to float, then divide it by 100.

So, this:

```
df_centers['cost']  = df_centers['cost'].astype('int')
df_centers['usage'] = df_centers['usage'].astype('float')
```

should be:

```
df_centers['cost']  = df_centers['cost'].str.lstrip('$').astype('int')
#                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
df_centers['usage'] = df_centers['usage'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0
#                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary02127 for the suggestion, i tried a simpler method, but will try using the .lstrip and .rstrip as well. Appreciate the answer and gave you a +1

Comment: Sorry, but this just doesn't work with pandas.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  My apologies for providing an incorrect answer. I have updated my answer to be in proper pandas format.