# Converting all the data in percentages to decimals (python)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I am trying to create a heat map but the plot just returns an empty 2D object with no plot. I suspect its because my values are in percentages. is there a function for me to convert all the values to floats? Thank you.

[image: a screenshot of the dataset]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert percent string to float in pandas read\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669588/convert-percent-string-to-float-in-pandas-read-csv)

Comment: yeah it does, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the `pd.DataFrame` was already created, one approach is to use [pandas replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['10.1%','20.25%'],['40.45%', '50.52%'], ['30.3%', '60.7%']], columns=['foo', 'bar'])
```

[image]

You can use `replace` to get rid of the `%` sign:

```
df = df.replace('%','', regex=True)
```

[image]

Finally, you could cast all columns to `np.float64` as needed:

```
df.astype(np.float64)
```