# Error while converting object to int in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, error-code, dtype

so I'm having problems converting an object to an int in python. my code is

```
df['non_renewable'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

however, when I do this, I get the error code

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100%'

what are some solutions to this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert percent string to float in pandas read\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669588/convert-percent-string-to-float-in-pandas-read-csv) Essentially just do something like `df['non_renewable'].str.rstrip('%').astype(int)`

Comment: `100%` isn't a number. You can't just cast it to an integer. What do you expect as a result? 1? 100?