# What is a clean way to convert a string percent to a float using the example provided below?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point

I'm looking for a more 'dumbed-down' version of a solution to this issue I have. Below is the code I have.

I'm trying to allow for both the % symbol and simply a number as input for the percentage from user.anyone that can help me would have to write this out for me more than the [previous examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432663/what-is-a-clean-way-to-convert-a-string-percent-to-a-float/40881904#40881904) explain please.

```
#104 Percentages
print('#104 Percentages')
percent = float(input('Enter percentage: '))
decimal = percent/100
print('Equivalent decimal:',round(decimal,2))
print()
```

Comment: You can `input(...).strip('%')` to allow for `%` or not. And just format the output rather than `round()`, e.g. `print('Equivalent decimal: {:.2f}'.format(decimal))`. But isn't this already answered in the post you've linked to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a clean way to convert a string percent to a float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432663/what-is-a-clean-way-to-convert-a-string-percent-to-a-float)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your feedback. ShadowRanger (shown below) fixed me up good with code i could use verbatm.

Answer (score 2):

The question you linked has answers describing the use of `str.strip` (though `rstrip` would be more appropriate) to remove the trailing `%` if it exists. Just do that on the return from `input` before you pass it to `float`, changing the line to:

```
percent = float(input('Enter percentage: ').rstrip('%'))
```

If you'd like it split up for clarity:

```
maybe_percent_sign_str = input('Enter percentage: ')
no_percent_sign_str = maybe_percent_sign_str.rstrip('%')
percent = float(no_percent_sign_str)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much ShadowRanger! You've solved my issue. I appreciate the way you answered this...Excellent!