# Trouble converting string to float in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to Python so forgive me this simple question. I'm trying to convert string to float. Here is a sample of the data:

```
0     10.65%
1      7.90%
```

When I try:

```
 df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].astype('float')
```

I get:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '13.75%'
```

When I try:

```
df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].replace("%","", inplace=True)
```

And check my data, I get:

```
0     None
1     None
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'][:-1].astype('float') cause: % can't convert to float

Comment: `df['int_rate'].apply(lambda x: x.rstrip("%")).astype(float)`

Comment: have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432663/what-is-a-clean-way-to-convert-a-string-percent-to-a-float

Comment: `df['int_rate'] = float( df['int_rate'].replace("%",""))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with parameter `regex=True` for replace `substring`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'int_rate':['10.65%','7.90%']})
df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].replace("%","", regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
   int_rate
0     10.65
1      7.90
```

Or [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].str.replace("%","")
print (df)
  int_rate
0    10.65
1     7.90
2
```

Or [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].str.rstrip("%").astype(float)
print (df)
   int_rate
0     10.65
1      7.90
```

See difference without it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'int_rate':['10.65%','7.90%', '%']})

df['int_rate_subs'] = df['int_rate'].replace("%","", regex=True)
df['int_rate_val'] = df['int_rate'].replace("%","")
print (df)
  int_rate int_rate_subs int_rate_val
0   10.65%         10.65       10.65%
1    7.90%          7.90        7.90%
2        %
```

Comment: Yes, I also found that setting `regex=True` makes it work, however, can you explain why? At first I thought the problem to be that the `%` needs to be escaped with `%%` (as requred by old style string interpolation), but that makes no difference. I don't get why treating `%` as a regex fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jezrael and others for chipping in. Regex=True did the trick. As mhawke, I would also be curious as to why? Many thanks!

Comment: Really hard get nice answer, but `replace` looks for exact matches unless you pass a regex pattern and param `regex=True`

Comment: Thanks Jezrael, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

As you guessed, `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '13.75%'` indicates that the `%` character blocks the convertion.

Now when you try to remove it:

```
df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].replace("%","", inplace=True)
```

You set `inplace=True` in your replacement, which as the name suggests changes the dataframe in-place, so `replace()` method call returns `None`. Thus you store `None` in `df['int_rate']` and end up with a column containing only `None` values.
You should either do:

```
df['int_rate'] = df['int_rate'].replace("%","")
```

or

```
df['int_rate'].replace("%","", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, Guillaume. That makes sense. However, for some bizarre reason, the % sign is not coming off with either method. The rows remain unchanged. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using a string, you could convert the value to a float using

```
float(df['int_rate'][:-1])
```

This reads the string from the first position to the second to last position, 10.65 instead of 10.65%.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I get TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: No problem, Minsky, what version of Python are you using? I'll take a closer look at the issue to see if I can replicate the error you're receiving.
I should add that I'm using 3.6.1 above.

Comment: Appreciate it. I'm on Python 3.6. I'm practicing on the Lending Club data-set (directly from their website).

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using the Anaconda version of 3.6. The complete error message is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\avesu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-56-340f2d2704e2>", line 1, in <module>
    float(df['int_rate'][:-1])
  File "C:\Users\avesu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 97, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>